# How do I exactly use try-catches for fault handling?

Tags: c#, .net-core, try-catch, try-catch-finally

So currently I need to implement try-catches, but everywhere I look the try-catch can be relevant. How do you determine where to use the try-catches?

Is there also a generalized way how to implement the try-catches? For example Is there some way how an empty class can be used in Faulthandling as indicated below?

```
public class FailedRoleManager : IRoleManager { }
```

Comment: Exceptions is the answer for the following problem: the code which detects an error usually doesn't know what to do with it. So it simply propagates the error until it reaches the code which knows what to do with the error. Therefore, use `try-catch` in places where you both might expect an exception and knows what to do with it.

Comment: So basically I can always use the try-catches in my HomeController (..NET Core MVC App) since it calls many other parts of code, hence placing it on the 'highest level'?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of project you are doing, it is possible to make a middleware that handles all the exceptions that occurred in the application. In this link you can see an example of an implementation of global error capture in a .net core api:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            var response = context.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { message = error?.Message });
            await response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
}
```

[https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/02/aspnet-core-31-global-error-handler-tutorial#:~:text=The%20global%20error%20handler%20middleware%20is%20used%20catch%20all%20exceptions,Configure%20method%20of%20the%20Startup](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/02/aspnet-core-31-global-error-handler-tutorial#:%7E:text=The%20global%20error%20handler%20middleware%20is%20used%20catch%20all%20exceptions,Configure%20method%20of%20the%20Startup).

Comment: How will I know all the possible exceptions like mentioned in the link like the AppException and KeyNotFoundException?

Comment: You dont need to know all the possibles exceptions. You can simply do a catch to Exception, and treat like an internal error. I edited the answer to add an example.